# nth-of-type not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">          
    <div id="ok" class="content-block warning"><div></div><span>&#10003 Everything is OK!</span> </div>         
    <div id="module_1" class="content-block small">asfdasdf</div>
    <div id="module_2" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</div>
    <div id="module_3" class="content-block small">asfasdf</div>
    <div id="module_4" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</div>
    <div id="module_5" class="content-block small">asfasdf</div>
    <div id="module_6" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</div>
    <div id="module_7" class="content-block big"></div> 
    <div id="module_8" class="content-block big"></div>     
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.small:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-color: black;
}

.small:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/CNBsY/2/  I can't quite figure out why `nth-of-type(1)` doesn't select anything while `nth-of-type(2)` selects the first thing I want to select. Does anybody understand why this is happening?

Comment: It's because the type of the first line and the first "asdafs" is the same.

Comment: `nth-of-type` works on elements, not classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's `nth-of-type`, not `nth-of-class`.

First `div` in your HTML does not have `small` class, so there is no element matching both `.small` and `nth-of-type(1)`.

Comment: No, there is nothing like `nth-of-class` in CSS right now.

Comment: Thank you! So is it correct that line of CSS is basically interpreted like: "1. find the type of element of the selector 2. search the whole page for all elements with that type 3. select all nth elements 4. select only the elements that satisfy the selector"

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo selector `:nth-of-type()` selects the **type of tag**.

In your example it is a `div`. As you set the selector on the class (`.small:nth-of-type(1)`) the css is aplied only if the first div has that class which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

HTML

```
<div id="content">          
    <span id="ok" class="content-block warning">&#10003 Everything is OK!</span>
    <ul>         
        <li id="module_1" class="content-block small">asfdasdf</li>
        <li id="module_2" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</li>
        <li id="module_3" class="content-block small">asfasdf</li>
        <li id="module_4" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</li>
        <li id="module_5" class="content-block small">asfasdf</li>
        <li id="module_6" class="content-block small">asdfasdf</li>
        <li id="module_7" class="content-block big"></li> 
        <li id="module_8" class="content-block big"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-color: black;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

It's a better semantic.